# How do I select a sub-folder as a directory containing tests in Python extension for Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode with python code and I have a folder with sub-directories (2-levels deep) containing python tests.

When I try "Python: Discover Tests" it asks for a test framework (selected pytest) and the directory in which tests exist. At this option, it shows only the top-level directories and does not allow to select a sub-directory.

I tried to type the directory path but it does not accept it.

Can someone please help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

I solved it by putting this in my `settings.json`:

`"python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my-project/all-tests/unit-tests"`

In the GUI, the setting name is "Python > Testing: Cwd".

If you then get the error `No file or directory "unit-tests"`, try this:

1. Open the test configuration dialogue (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P -> "Python: Configure Tests")
2. Select `pytest` or `unittest`
3. Select `.` (Root Directory) - *Earlier I had selected the `unit-tests` directory instead*

If it still isn't working, you might be running into [this open bug with `${workspaceFolder}`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11671).

If it *still* isn't working, open up the "Output" window and select "Python" to see more info.

Also, this conversation was helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11587

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. One is to leave the selection as-is and make sure your directories are packages by adding `__init__.py` files as appropriate. The other is you can go into your workspace settings and adjust the `"python.testing.pytestArgs"` setting as appropriate to point to your tests.

Comment: 2nd option didn't work for me. specifying the subdirectory in `python.testing.pytestArgs` still lets VSCode search in the top level directory

Answer (score 0):

Silly solution:

Go to "file", select "open folder" and pick the directory one level above your "tests" folder. Then it will let you pick "tests" as the testing ground.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to do (which for some reason didn't seem obvious to me at first):

`pip install pytest`

I selected *unittest* in the VS Code config window and then selected *(.) root folder*. It found my tests in my subfolders (more than 2 levels deep) just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening the "Output" log (Ctrl+Shift+U) and run "Python: Discover Tests". Alternatively, you may type `pytest --collect-only` into the console. Maybe you are experiencing some errors with the tests themselves (such as importing errors).

Also, make sure to keep `__init__.py` file in your "tests" folder.

I am keeping the pytest "tests" folder within a subdirectory, and there are no issues with VS Code discovering the tests.